# TCPDF - Codeigniter - Failed to load PDF document

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf

Controller:

```
public function test(){
    $data = array();
    $this->load->library('tcpdf');
    $this->display_page($data);
}
```

test.php: (Not posting all of it, as its a bit long)

```
global $l;
$l = Array();
$l['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$l['a_meta_dir'] = 'ltr';
$l['a_meta_language'] = 'en';
$l['w_page'] = 'page';

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8',              false);


-- pdf stuff -- 

$pdf->Output('example_007.pdf', 'I');
```

In Chrome, it just says "Failed to load PDF document.".  No errors, nothing in console. 
In firefox, it says: "File does not begin with '%PDF-'. Local\EWH`_'s3-0y".

The string at the end of Local\ appears random with each load.

I have tried using output buffering and flush, to no avail. I am at a loss.

Answer (score 7):

Try to put **`exit;`** after outputting pdf. I hope it will fix that like it did for me.

-- pdf stuff --

```
$pdf->Output('example_007.pdf', 'I');
exit;
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
ob_clean();
ob_flush();
$pdf->Output('example_007.pdf', 'I');
ob_end_flush();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are outputting something to the browser before you are generating the invoice. Go to the source of the page and see if there is anything, including white spaces (new lines or spaces) and remove them.

Comment: Yeah I have seen this suggestion a lot and it doesn't seem to be the issue here, thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try just including the tcpdf file? That shouldn't be the issue, but you never know.

Comment: I have :( This is so annoying. I don't know why I am the only person on the interwebs having this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Duniyadnd is correct. When I looked at the network response in the debug tools in Chrome, I saw that the '%PDF-' magic was on the second line and not the first. I discovered some whitespace in my required include files before and after the  delimiters which was outputting to the browser before the pdf file. Eliminating this whitespace before and after the php delimiters cured the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using YII FRAMEWORK, ensure that you renderPartial and not render the view in your controller

Comment: This answer does not reply to the OP question, since there is no information about YII in OP question. To ask for clarification or more info, please use comments.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with that problem for a very long time. Below is what works for me:

```
require_once 'tcpdf/tcpdf.php';
ob_start();
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
.......
$pdf->lastPage();
ob_end_clean();
ob_clean();
$pdf->Output('payment_report_'.$debtor.'.pdf', 'D');
ob_end_flush();
exit;
```

Note: ob_start() just above $pdf = new TCPDF.... and the code at the end of the file.